# Compilation headers for 64-bit ARM64 Raspberry Pi for Yate?

Tags: c, arm64

When I try to compile Nuand's [Yate](https://github.com/Nuand/bladeRF/wiki/Setting-up-Yate-and-YateBTS-with-the-bladeRF#building-and-installing-yate--yatebts) software on 64-bit (ARM64) Ubuntu 21.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4, I get architecture support headers errors:

```
~/software/bts/yate$ make
make -C ./engine all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/parallels/software/bts/yate/engine'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/parallels/software/bts/yate/engine'
make -C ./modules all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/parallels/software/bts/yate/modules'
make -C ../libs/miniwebrtc
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/parallels/software/bts/yate/libs/miniwebrtc'
g++ -Wall   -I. -I./audio/common/processing -I./audio/common/vad -I./audio/processing/aec -I./audio/processing/aecm -I./audio/processing/agc -I./audio/processing/ns -I./audio/processing/utility -I./system_wrappers -O2 -Wno-overloaded-virtual  -fno-exceptions -fPIC -DHAVE_GCC_FORMAT_CHECK -DHAVE_BLOCK_RETURN  -DWEBRTC_NS_FLOAT=true -c -o audio/common/resampler/resampler.o audio/common/resampler/resampler.cc
In file included from ./audio/common/processing/signal_processing_library.h:22,
                 from audio/common/resampler/resampler.cc:19:
./typedefs.h:104:2: error: #error Please add support for your architecture in typedefs.h
  104 | #error Please add support for your architecture in typedefs.h
      |  ^~~~~
make[2]: *** [Makefile:263: audio/common/resampler/resampler.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/parallels/software/bts/yate/libs/miniwebrtc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:448: ../libs/miniwebrtc/libminiwebrtc.a] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/parallels/software/bts/yate/modules'
make: *** [Makefile:186: modules] Error 2
```

When I check the typedefs.h header, I see arm64 support is not added yet:

```
/*
 *  Copyright (c) 2011 The WebRTC project authors. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *  Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license
 *  that can be found in the LICENSE file in the root of the source
 *  tree. An additional intellectual property rights grant can be found
 *  in the file PATENTS.  All contributing project authors may
 *  be found in the AUTHORS file in the root of the source tree.
 */

// This file contains platform-specific typedefs and defines.
#ifndef WEBRTC_TYPEDEFS_H_
#define WEBRTC_TYPEDEFS_H_

// Reserved words definitions
// TODO(andrew): Look at removing these.
#define WEBRTC_EXTERN extern
#define G_CONST const
#define WEBRTC_INLINE extern __inline

// Define WebRTC preprocessor identifiers based on the current build platform.
// TODO(andrew): Clean these up. We can probably remove everything in this
// block.
//   - TARGET_MAC_INTEL and TARGET_MAC aren't used anywhere.
//   - In the few places where TARGET_PC is used, it should be replaced by
//     something more specific.
//   - Do we really support PowerPC? Probably not. Remove WEBRTC_MAC_INTEL
//     from build/common.gypi as well.
#if defined(WIN32)
    // Windows & Windows Mobile.
    #if !defined(WEBRTC_TARGET_PC)
        #define WEBRTC_TARGET_PC
    #endif
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
    // Mac OS X.
    #if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN__ )
        #if !defined(WEBRTC_TARGET_MAC_INTEL)
            #define WEBRTC_TARGET_MAC_INTEL
        #endif
    #else
        #if !defined(WEBRTC_TARGET_MAC)
            #define WEBRTC_TARGET_MAC
        #endif
    #endif
#else
    // Linux etc.
    #if !defined(WEBRTC_TARGET_PC)
        #define WEBRTC_TARGET_PC
    #endif
#endif

// Derived from Chromium's build/build_config.h
// Processor architecture detection.  For more info on what's defined, see:
//   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx
//   http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf
//   or with gcc, run: "echo | gcc -E -dM -"
// TODO(andrew): replace WEBRTC_LITTLE_ENDIAN with WEBRTC_ARCH_LITTLE_ENDIAN?
#if defined(_M_X64) || defined(__x86_64__)
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_X86_FAMILY
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_X86_64
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_64_BITS
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_LITTLE_ENDIAN
#elif defined(_M_IX86) || defined(__i386__)
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_X86_FAMILY
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_X86
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_32_BITS
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_LITTLE_ENDIAN
#elif defined(__ARMEL__)
// TODO(andrew): We'd prefer to control platform defines here, but this is
// currently provided by the Android makefiles. Commented to avoid duplicate
// definition warnings.
//#define WEBRTC_ARCH_ARM
// TODO(andrew): Chromium uses the following two defines. Should we switch?
//#define WEBRTC_ARCH_ARM_FAMILY
//#define WEBRTC_ARCH_ARMEL
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_32_BITS
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_LITTLE_ENDIAN
#elif defined(__mips__)
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_32_BITS
#define WEBRTC_BIG_ENDIAN
#elif defined(__powerpc64__)
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_PPC64 1
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_64_BITS
#ifdef __LITTLE_ENDIAN__
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_LITTLE_ENDIAN
#define WEBRTC_LITTLE_ENDIAN
#else
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_BIG_ENDIAN
#define WEBRTC_BIG_ENDIAN
#endif
#elif defined(__powerpc__)
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_PPC 1
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_32_BITS
#ifdef __LITTLE_ENDIAN__
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_LITTLE_ENDIAN
#define WEBRTC_LITTLE_ENDIAN
#else
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_BIG_ENDIAN
#define WEBRTC_BIG_ENDIAN
#endif

#else
#error Please add support for your architecture in typedefs.h
#endif

#if defined(__SSE2__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
#define WEBRTC_USE_SSE2
#endif

#if defined(WEBRTC_TARGET_PC)

#if !defined(_MSC_VER)
  #include <stdint.h>
#else
    // Define C99 equivalent types.
    // Since MSVC doesn't include these headers, we have to write our own
    // version to provide a compatibility layer between MSVC and the WebRTC
    // headers.
    typedef signed char         int8_t;
    typedef signed short        int16_t;
    typedef signed int          int32_t;
    typedef signed long long    int64_t;
    typedef unsigned char       uint8_t;
    typedef unsigned short      uint16_t;
    typedef unsigned int        uint32_t;
    typedef unsigned long long  uint64_t;
#endif

#if defined(WIN32)
    typedef __int64             WebRtc_Word64;
    typedef unsigned __int64    WebRtc_UWord64;
#else
    typedef int64_t             WebRtc_Word64;
    typedef uint64_t            WebRtc_UWord64;
#endif
    typedef int32_t             WebRtc_Word32;
    typedef uint32_t            WebRtc_UWord32;
    typedef int16_t             WebRtc_Word16;
    typedef uint16_t            WebRtc_UWord16;
    typedef char                WebRtc_Word8;
    typedef uint8_t             WebRtc_UWord8;

    // Define endian for the platform
    #define WEBRTC_LITTLE_ENDIAN

#elif defined(WEBRTC_TARGET_MAC_INTEL)
    #include <stdint.h>

    typedef int64_t             WebRtc_Word64;
    typedef uint64_t            WebRtc_UWord64;
    typedef int32_t             WebRtc_Word32;
    typedef uint32_t            WebRtc_UWord32;
    typedef int16_t             WebRtc_Word16;
    typedef char                WebRtc_Word8;
    typedef uint16_t            WebRtc_UWord16;
    typedef uint8_t             WebRtc_UWord8;

    // Define endian for the platform
    #define WEBRTC_LITTLE_ENDIAN

#else
    #error "No platform defined for WebRTC type definitions (typedefs.h)"
#endif

#endif  // WEBRTC_TYPEDEFS_H_
```

So I reported this error to manufacturer Nuand, but they were not responding quickly on how to resolve these issues. So if I would add support for the raspberry pi manually, What's the correct way to add support for ARM64 without resulting into errors after compilation?

I tried:

```
#elif defined(__aarch64__)
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_64_BITS
#define WEBRTC_ARCH_LITTLE_ENDIAN
```

But it didn't result into a working Yate binary:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yate/yate-rc-2/yate/conf.d'
make: *** [Makefile:259: install-api] Error 1
```

Comment: *make: *** [Makefile:259: install-api] Error 1* - That's not a useful error message.  It's just telling you that something earlier exited with an error.  The earlier error messages should tell you what.

Comment: You should first check where these macros are actually used. Find that first and then see what changes you need to do in order to make it work for aarch64.

Comment: Probably `$ patch -p1 < add-arm64-support.patch` .... ref. source package `yate-6.4.0-pm153.5.1.src.rpm` ......... ( $ wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/packman.iu-bremen.de/suse/openSUSE_Leap_15.3/Extra/src/yate-6.4.0-pm153.5.1.src.rpm ) Patch : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n1uCWpSZMMV45ptUYeqFVRWYWBWirKxN/view?usp=sharing .......... typedefs.h → `+#elif defined(__aarch64__)` ..... etc. etc.

Comment: @KnudLarsen that's the exact same patch that OP already tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**The patch you applied is really necessary to build Yate for arm64**.

Installation finishes without errors if you run install-noapi:

```bash
sudo make install-noapi
```

Comment: I tried that `sudo make install-noapi` it didn't work for me. Encountered that error when I was running on a raspberry-pi model 4B, with a bladeRF A9 model.